# PC powers up but there is no display

Tags: boot

I built a computer with standard components I bought from Newegg about three years ago.  It ran great for 2 years and has sat powered down for the last year.  I tried to power it up today and the display was blank.  It powers up, lights come on, drives start spinning but there is nothing on the display.  I verified that the monitor and video adapter work.  I also tried the video adapter in a different slot on the mother board with no luck.  What's the next thing I should try?  Is the mother board shot?

Thanks.

Comment: Please tell us how you verified that the monitor and video car work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try to change the RAM and clean the memory slots. Faulty memory chips might also be the problem.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4701856/how-do-i-make-server-from-laptop-with-broken-video-card/4701964#4701964

Comment: I didn't have to change the RAM fortunately but taking the sticks out and putting them back in a couple times seems to have done the trick. Glad I don't have to buy new parts but bummed I don't have to buy new parts, too.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this post: [Computer powers off then tries to start up but resets repeatedly](https://superuser.com/questions/232950/computer-powers-off-then-tries-to-start-up-but-resets-repeatedly)

And follow my instructions in it, just in case you really want to find out what component you might need to replace. The worst case scenario would be a broken motherboard, but before buying a new one, you'll want to be absolutely positive that no other component is causing this problem.

Comment: If the display worked then I could boot into BIOS and do those things.

Comment: You can still troubleshoot according to the rest of that post. The bit about the BIOS was specific to that user. I've been in exactly your position and found that my mobo was the culprit, but I made sure I was 100% sure of it before buying a new one. Any part of your computer could cause it to hang right on boot.